# Solr Auto Expiry of Documents in Collection

Tags: solr

Using Solr 6.0.0, I followed [this walkthrough](https://lucidworks.com/blog/2014/05/07/document-expiration/) for configuration of auto-expiry of documents in collection.

1. My default solrconfig.xml has only addition (as per walkthrough suggestion)

   ```
   <!-- auto delete collection -->
   <updateRequestProcessorChain default="true">
   <processor class="solr.TimestampUpdateProcessorFactory">
     <str name="fieldName">timestamp_dt</str>
   </processor>
   <processor class="solr.processor.DocExpirationUpdateProcessorFactory">
     <int name="autoDeletePeriodSeconds">30</int>
     <str name="ttlFieldName">time_to_live_s</str>
     <str name="expirationFieldName">expire_at_dt</str>
   </processor>
   <processor class="solr.FirstFieldValueUpdateProcessorFactory">
     <str name="fieldName">expire_at_dt</str>
   </processor>
   <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
   <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
   ```
2. I created collection with above configuration;

   ```
   bin/solr create -c tweets -d tweets_configs -s 1 -rf 1
   ```
3. Inserted documents

   ```
   date -u && curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'http://localhost:8983/solr/tweets/update?commit=true' -d '[{"id":"live_forever"},{"id":"live_2_minutes_a", "time_to_live_s":"+120SECONDS"}]'
   ```

   and

   ```
   date -u && curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json'    
   'http://localhost:8983/solr/tweets/update?commit=true&_ttl_=%2B5MINUTES' -d
   '[{"id":"live_a_long_time",
   "expire_at_dt":"3000-01-01T00:00:00Z"   },
   {"id":"live_2_minutes_b",
   "time_to_live_s":"+120SECONDS"},
   {"id":"use_default_ttl"}]'
   ```
4. But when I query the documents, there is no expiry set as should have been there as per walkthrough;

   ```
   {
     "responseHeader":{
       "zkConnected":true,
       "status":0,
       "QTime":19,
       "params":{
         "q":"*:*",
         "indent":"on",
         "wt":"json"}},
     "response":{"numFound":5,"start":0,"docs":[
         {
           "id":"live_forever",
           "_version_":1533920832055672832},
         {
           "id":"live_2_minutes_a",
           "time_to_live_s":"+120SECONDS",
           "_version_":1533920832086081536},
         {
           "id":"live_a_long_time",
           "expire_at_dt":"3000-01-01T00:00:00Z",
           "_version_":1533921242796523520},
         {
           "id":"live_2_minutes_b",
           "time_to_live_s":"+120SECONDS",
           "_version_":1533921242825883648},
         {
           "id":"use_default_ttl",
           "_version_":1533921242829029376}]
     }}
   ```

whereas I was expecting to see expiry automatically set as per multiple mechanisms configured in step1.

Does it work differently in 6.0.0 than 4.8? Or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had only one default updateRequestProcessorChain but as I started with the data_driven_schema_configs configset, and modified that to include my new updateRequestProcessorChain, it's not used because I had;

```
<initParams path="/update/**">
 <lst name="defaults">
   <str name="update.chain">add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema</str>
 </lst>
</initParams>
```

was forcing "add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema" updateRequestProcessorChain to be used.

I had to comment this and update my default with desired processors to make auto expiry work. Very powerful feature indeed!

Credits to [Chris Hostetter](https://people.apache.org/~hossman/) for answering on solr-user list.